# How best to incorporate a comment into an answer?

Tags: support, answers, comments

Two comments to [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/67800/23970) would, I think, be nice to incorporate into the answer proper. Is there a way to do this wholesale, or do I effectively need to re-create each of the commenter's references from scratch?

I don't mind that tiny bit of work. It just seems that a way to absorb the comment in would nicely (a) preserve a bit of a byline for the original comment author and then (b) remove the comment from their section, so it's not redundant. If there's a way to do that, I'd like to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a standard way to incorporate comments into your answer, but if you are using quotes from the comments or just copying them into your answer, you do need to attribute them to be compliant with the CC-BY-SA license.

In order to incorporate them seamlessly, I recommend adding a parenthetical with a link to the user profile of the user noting that the idea/quote you are using is contributed by another user.

Just because comments are ephemeral does *not* mean they are not protected by the CC-BY-SA license.

Comment: Would mentioning the user and their comment in your edit summary be sufficient attribution?

Comment: @DanHenderson You'd have to check the license, I think it has to be visible though.

Comment: Note that this is only for copying or copying and altering the text of comments. If it's just using the idea (“here is a link you might want to use”, etc.), then no copyright (and therefore no licensing) is involved. (URLs themselves are function speech, not creative, and not covered by copyright.)

Answer (score 3):

You manually recreate the references in your answer.

You don't need to attribute the comments' authors - they should know that comments are temporary, and are intended to help improve your answer.